# How to resolve or skip particular line of column where we get > "float object is not iterable" in str.findall

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Hi I am trying to iterate over a column in pandas.
I tried replacing 'i' with '[i]'. But it gave rise to different error.
I have the small input, not the entire input.
Or is also possible that we can skip such a row in dataframe where we get error : "'float' object is not iterable" and it continues to iterate in next rows ?

Input:

```
Name    Matches
John    [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]
Wall    [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]
Austin  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]
```

Code:

```
df['any_value_greater_than_10?'] = (['yes' if any(int(a)>10 for a in i) else 'no' 
                                       for i in df['Matches'].str.findall('\d+')])
```

Error:

```
for i in df['Matches'].str.findall('\d+')])
'float' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Is possible add some sample data? how working `int(a)` to `float(a)` ?

Comment: What is your pandas version? For me working nice.

Answer (score 1):

For me working nice if convert values to strings, also added some empty list for better test if no data match:

```
print (df)
     Name                                Matches
0    John  [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]
1    Wall                 [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]
2  Austin                  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]
3    Josh                                     []


print (df['Matches'].astype(str).str.findall('\d+'))
0    [1, 0, 500, 2, 0, 600, 70, 67, 78]
1                  [4, 0, 14, 2, 0, 40]
2                    [1, 0, 5, 0, 2, 7]
3                                    []
Name: Matches, dtype: object

df['any_value_greater_than_10?'] = (['yes' if any(int(a)>10 for a in i) else 'no' 
                                      for i in df['Matches'].astype(str).str.findall('\d+')])

print (df)
     Name                                Matches any_value_greater_than_10?
0    John  [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]                        yes
1    Wall                 [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]                        yes
2  Austin                  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]                         no
3    Josh                                     []                         no
```

Another solution:

```
m = (df['Matches'].astype(str)
                  .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
                  .astype(float)
                  .gt(10)
                  .any(level=0)
                  .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False))

df['any_value_greater_than_10?'] = np.where(m, 'yes','no')

print (df)
     Name                                Matches any_value_greater_than_10?
0    John  [1, 0, 500,], [2, 0, 600,],[70,67,78]                        yes
1    Wall                 [4, 0, 14], [2, 0, 40]                        yes
2  Austin                  [1, 0, 5,], [0,2, 7,]                         no
3    Josh                                     []                         no
```

**How it working**:

After converting to strings is used [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for all integers to column `0`:

```
print (df['Matches'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\d+)'))
           0
  match     
0 0        1
  1        0
  2      500
  3        2
  4        0
  5      600
  6       70
  7       67
  8       78
1 0        4
  1        0
  2       14
  3        2
  4        0
  5       40
2 0        1
  1        0
  2        5
  3        0
  4        2
  5        7
```

For Series is selected column `0`:

```
print (df['Matches'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\d+)')[0])
   match
0  0          1
   1          0
   2        500
   3          2
   4          0
   5        600
   6         70
   7         67
   8         78
1  0          4
   1          0
   2         14
   3          2
   4          0
   5         40
2  0          1
   1          0
   2          5
   3          0
   4          2
   5          7
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Convert to floats and then test for greater like `10`:

```
print (df['Matches'].astype(str)
                      .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
                      .astype(float)
                      .gt(10)
)
   match
0  0        False
   1        False
   2         True
   3        False
   4        False
   5         True
   6         True
   7         True
   8         True
1  0        False
   1        False
   2         True
   3        False
   4        False
   5         True
2  0        False
   1        False
   2        False
   3        False
   4        False
   5        False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Last check if at least one `True` per first level created by original index values:

```
print (df['Matches'].astype(str)
                      .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
                      .astype(float)
                      .gt(10)
                      .any(level=0))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

... and add some non matche rows, here last one:

```
print (df['Matches'].astype(str)
                      .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
                      .astype(float)
                      .gt(10)
                      .any(level=0)
                      .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False))

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

And last last is passed to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

Comment: Can you add your version?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin - `pandas 1.0.1`, but problem here is there are lists with numbers, so edited answer.

Comment: @jezrael: are we using [0] in ".str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]" to capture only first element or is it a flag ?

Comment: @Anonymus - No, it is column `0`, give me some time for explnation